# How to calculate number of qubits required for Grover Algorithm while constructing it's oracle and diffuser for any Specific Algorithm or Hash?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

I am reading a paper titled, " ([Towards Post-Quantum Secure Symmetric Cryptography:
A Mathematical Perspective](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1208))". Here, I am able to understand the gate counts and T-depth calculations. Although, I am unable to understand its significance. While, they just give the amount of qubits needed for specific operations. Is there any paper or method to calculate these needed qubits. Some steps are very clear on why they need additional qubits, while much of the steps I cannot understand.